# Users with Full Control cannot add documents to library by email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, email

I have a document library that allows documents to be added by email. It works fine when allowing emails from anyone, but when only allowing users based on the document library permissions the attached document doesn't get added. I've made sure that I have Full Control permissions for the site and the document libraries.  When looking at the logs using SharePoint LogViewer I get an error saying:

"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Has anyone had this issue and/or know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

is you set the credentials for the context?
i think you missed this so it gives you a error

context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.UserName, this.Password, this.Domain);

Answer (score 0):

The article is a bit old but it explains what could be the problem:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287981(v=office.12).aspx

> To allow this feature to work, the document libraries allow anonymous
>   insertions from e-mail attachments. You cannot control who has rights
>   to add attached documents to this document library. However, you can
>   control who can add documents directly to the document library, and
>   you can control who has rights to post to the public folder by using
>   the Exchange user management tools.

Comment: So what this is saying is that the only way to allow users to add documents via emailed attachments is to accept emails from all users?

Answer (score 0):

If the **Content Organizer** feature is activated in your site:

Make sure that the user has at least "Read" permission on the **Drop Off Library**  (in case the Drop Off Library has broken inheritance permission).

Comment: I have full control permissions for that library

Comment: I guess you've already tested to upload a document to that library via GUI? I had similar issues when permissions were not set correctly in corresponding "look-up lists" / site solumns / content types that are referenced in the document library.

Comment: Yea, I'm able to add a document and everything. I can add it with email but the setting has to be for allowing emails from everyone

Comment: I am at my wit's end. My last idea is to have a look if there are dropped e-mails at the server's mail drop directory at `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop`. Maybe the incoming e-mails or their content (recipient-address, sender-address, ...) are somehow "malformed".

Comment: The Drop folder is empty